# How do I completely remove mega sync client

Tags: sync, cloud, mega

I'm using mega service (http://mega.co.nz). 
I installed the sync client on my Ubuntu 14.10 and it works well.
But now I'm trying to configure a new account.
I did a purge to the mega sync pakckage :

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove megasync
```

and I deleted the associated folder.
But after the new install, mega detect my old mega account and it did'nt even create the folder!
I disconnected the old one but don't work!

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 14):

You have in your home directory a megasync configuration `~/.local/share/data/Mega Limited`. Configurations in your home directory are not deleted by simply uninstalling a package.

Remove this folder with:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/data/Mega\ Limited
```

For the future use `purge` instead of `remove` when you want config files to be gone as well.

Comment: thx A.B
thx. it works.

Comment: @user237966 Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓).

Comment: `--purge` does not remove configuration files located in the home directory.

Answer (score 9):

To clear the mega client configuration must be eliminated.

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove megasync
```

and then delete the configuration

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/data/Mega\ Limited
```

Comment: The command `sudo apt-get --purge remove megasync` has been executed by the OP and is unnecessary in the response. Apart from that your answer does not provide new information that was not already written in other answers.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Other answers  mention that `--purge` will remove configuration files located in the home directory too. This is not true. So the correct sequence is this.